# how to use security function without delay in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm using security function like below:

```
indicator("My script" , overlay = true)

mystate = close[0] >= open[0] and close[1] >= open[1] and close[2] >= open[2] and close[3] >= open[3] and close[4] >= open[4]

transtate = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", mystate)

plotshape(transtate,  
          size=size.small,  
          style= shape.triangledown, 
          color=color.red,  
          text = 'this', 
          textcolor=color.red)
```

it means plot the candle when 5 green candle Continuous.

so it plot 1:30 in time frame 30

and when switch time frame to 15 the plots are on 1:45 and 2:00

and in time frame 5 the plots are on 1:55 , 2:00 , 2:05 , 2:10 , 2:15 , 2:20

how can I get plots immediately in right time( in example above in 1:30) in all time frame ?

picture below is in time frame 5 minute
[image]

picture below is in time frame 30 minute
[image]

I tried to plot candles on time frame 30 with security function and see the plot shape on lower time frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `barmerge.lookahead_on` parameter of the `security()` function to match the start of the higher timeframe bar with the first one in the same period on lower tf

```
transtate = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", mystate, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Note that the security with lookahead leaks future data on historical bars.

If you would like to plot only on the first lower tf bar, replace the condition in plotshape to:

```
plotshape(transtate and not nz(transtate[1]), ...
```

Comment: thanks so much, it is right, but how to plot only first candle? in time frame 5 it still 6 plotshape.

Comment: can I use the security as an alert condition? I mean set the alert in time frame 5 and use security to check higher time frame like 10, 15 , 30 ?

Comment: The scripts check if the condition is satisfied before it happens (at the closing of the 30 minute bar mark the first 5 minute bar in that period), so the conditions will not fire the same way you see on the historical charts.